# How can I solve this "IndexError: index 774 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 724"?

Tags: python, gis, raster, geopandas

**Code:**

```
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio as rio

capital_cities = gpd.read_file(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHP\Bangladesh_shapefile_Feature.shp')

capital_cities['Temp']=0

for index, row in capital_cities.iterrows() :
    city= row['DISTNAME']
    longitude=row['geometry'].x
    latitude=row['geometry'].y

    temp_raster = rio.open(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Output raster\c2019GDP_Clip.tif') 
    temp_data = temp_raster.read(1) 
    rowIndex, colIndex = temp_raster.index(longitude, latitude)
    print(city +':'+str(temp_data[rowIndex, colIndex]))
```

My primary objective is to export the data in the CSV file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To make sure I understand the problem: it seems that you expect, that where the code says `rowIndex, colIndex = temp_raster.index(longitude, latitude)`, this should make `rowIndex` and `colIndex` be valid index values to use for `temp_data`. In your own words, **why**? Did you try to check what `temp_data` contains? In particular, did you try to check its dimensions? "My primary objective is to export the data in csv file." I can't understand this. It looks like your code mentions a .shp file and a .tif file, nothing to do with CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine. It is working on my side...
I understand that what you re printing at the end is what you expect your csv to be (later, for now you re just output in console).
That error "IndexError: index 774 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 724" make me think to a projection system issue !!
Do both vector and raster layer have projection system defined properly? Are they in same projection system (must be...)?

Even with points that are not within the extent of the raster, you should have retrieved a nodata value (eg: -3.402823e+38 ), not raising an exception...

Comment: Please see [answer]. Answers should not seek clarification - that’s for comments. Also, [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question or answering](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - instead, copy it and paste it as a code block.